# Issue with Bigdecimal in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numerical-analysis

I have to calculate the following function:

```
f(x)=x^3-x-1
```

I've created a class, named "Function" and inside of it, I have a method calculating the above function.

Here comes my code:

```
double function(double num)
{
    BigDecimal first,second;
    double a,b,c,b_copy;
    a = Math.pow(num, 3);
    b=(double)a-num;
    first=new  BigDecimal(b);
    second=new BigDecimal("1.0");
    first.min(second);
    b_copy=first.doubleValue();
    return b_copy ;
}
```

I actually have some problems with these two lines of code:

```
    first.min(second);
    b_copy=first.doubleValue();
```

for example when `num` is 0 `b_copy` must be -1 but it is 0. Why is that?

Comment: `min` does not do subtraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `min(...)` method returns a `BigDecimal`, it doesn't modify it.
Try this:

```
first = first.min(second);
```

Also, if you want to subtract `1` from the value of `first` (as your formula indicates), use the `subtract(...)` method because `min(...)` actually returns the smallest values of the two `BigDecimal`s.

```
first = first.subtract(second);
```

Answer (score 4):

BigDecimal class is immutable. You cannot change, once it created.

When you change that object, it always returns a new Object.

```
first=new  BigDecimal(b);  //  you created an object
second=new BigDecimal("1.0");
first.min(second); // you just modifying it. Hence a new object returned and you never received.
```

To receive the newly created object, you can write

```
first = first.min(second);
```

When you write this, you are assigning the first with modified `BigDecimal` back

Not only `min()`, if you perform any operation on BigDecimal you need to reassign it back.